# Passing parameter to a function in C#

Tags: c#, function, parameter-passing

I have a small program. It includes a listbox and few textboxes. There are few elements in the listbox and depending on the selected index it outputs the corresponding values into the textboxes.

Code example: http://notepad.cc/share/AGh5zLNjfJ

I want to use a function to print the values into the textboxes instead of typing them over and over again in switch cases.

Something like this:

```
switch(personList.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        output(person1);
        break;
    case 1;
        output(person2);
        break;
}
```

I couldn't pass the person object and access its properties with the function I created. SOS.

Comment: "I couldn't pass the person object and access its properties with the function I created. " - why not? What happened when you tried? Also, please put your code *in the question* rather than just linking to it.

Comment: Do you want to output the value from the listbox into the textbox?

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought it'd be too long with the code in the post. Well, next time. And I tried this:
public void output(object x)
{
 idBox.Text = x.id;
 fnameBox.Text = x.name;
 lNameBox.Text = x.lName;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code i guess you need a function. you can do it like this

```
private void Output(Person p)
{
     idBox.Text = p.id;
     fnameBox.Text = p.name;
     lNameBox.Text = p.lName;
}
```

and call it like you are calling.

Comment: I was passing (object p) instead of Person. Well, I'm a newbie. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching by selected index, assign list of persons as data source to listbox. When selected index changes - show data of selected item in textboxes:

```
// that's just creating list of People with NBuilder
var people = Builder<Person>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build().ToList();
personList.DisplayMember = "fname"; // set name of property to be displayed
personList.DataSource = people;
```

Then on selecting person from list:

```
private void personList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person person = (Person)personList.SelectedItem;
    output(person);
}
```

Keep in mind that in C# we use PascalNaming for methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Is your output function similar to this ??

```
public void output(Person p)
{
    idBox.Text = p.id;
    nameBox.Text = p.name;
    lNameBox.Text = p.lName;
}
```

You can get selected Item as following (if you have bounded the listbox with list of person as datasource)

```
Person p = (Person)listBox1.SelectedItem;
```